# App Script Conditional Formatting to apply on sheet by name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to make a Google App Script code which highlight the cell if it has specific text like "L".

I have made a below code but its not working and when i run this no error appears. i do not know what is the problem.

Can you have a look at it, please that why its not working.

```
function formatting() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Dec');
  var range = sheet.getRange("C:AG");
  if (range == 'L') {
        ss.range.setBackgroundColor('#ea9999');
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issues with the code:

Three things to mention:

- `range` is a [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) object, not a string. In the `if` condition you are comparing an object of type `range` with an object of type `string`. You need to use [getValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) to get the values of the `range` object and then compare that with the string `L`.
- This code will take a lot of time to complete because you have a large range of cells you want to check but also you are iteratively using `GAS` API methods. As explained in [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) it is way more efficient to use batch operations like [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues),
  [getBackgrounds](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds) and [setBackgrounds](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor).
- Another improvement you can make is to use [getLastRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) to restrict the row limit of your range since you are looking for non-empty values. There is no reason for checking empty cells after the last row with content.

### Google Apps Script Solution:

```
function formatting() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Dec');
  const range = sheet.getRange("C1:AG"+sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues();
  const bcolors = range.getBackgrounds();
  const new_bcolors = values.map((r,i)=>r.map((c,j)=>c=='L'?'#ea9999':bcolors[i][j]))
  range.setBackgrounds(new_bcolors)
 }
```

### Google Sheets Solution:

Another idea would be to just create a conditional formatting in Google Sheets:

[image]

and specify a custom color with your hex code:

[image]

**JavaScript References:**

- [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Also note that they may want to use conditional formatting instead of Google Apps Script :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Marios and grateful that you explained it very briefly. thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @Martí true thanks, I added it for the shake of completion

Comment: @Strenuous I added a conditional formatting way of doing the same thing.

Comment: @Marios Thank you but there is a reason to go with script thank you.